# I want to edit the code GetProcessesByName

Tags: c#

I want anyone here to help me with this code used in my Trainer in a game I play online ... This code works well but in Clint only one and that game we open more than Clint and I wanted to play this code on All Clint for that game .. I hope you understand What i Mean .. thanks

```
private void nyX_CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender)
    {
        if (nyX_CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            Process pp = Process.GetProcessesByName("Game.exe")[0];
            IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, false, pp.Id);
            int written = 0;
            // make like ths
            byte[] write = { 0x00, 0x00 };
            //MildFz is smexy
            WriteProcessMemory((int)handle, 0x00, write, write.Length, ref written);
        }
        else if (nyX_CheckBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            Process pp = Process.GetProcessesByName("Game.exe")[0];
            IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, false, pp.Id);
            int written = 0;
            // make like ths
            byte[] write = {0x00, 0x00};
            //MildFz is smexy
            WriteProcessMemory((int)handle, 0x00, write, write.Length, ref written);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `if` seems unnecessary? The same code is executed regardless of whether `nyX_CheckBox1.Checked` is `true` or not.

Comment: i use themes in the trainer that's name him nyX ... but the checkBox Not True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you run multiple instance of game on a system and want to apply this code to all instance you should iterate over all game processes. your code should change to :

```
    Process[] pp = Process.GetProcessesByName("Game.exe");
    foreach (Process process in pp)
    {
        IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, false, process.Id);
        int written = 0;
        // make like ths
        byte[] write = { 0x00, 0x00 };
        //MildFz is smexy
        WriteProcessMemory((int)handle, 0x00, write, write.Length, ref written);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't even occur to me that's what the OP wants. If that's the case, it should definitely [marked as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/375646).